# JavaScript Event Passing quote

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a click event

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <button class="btn btn-small btn-danger btn-flat"  type="button" onclick="SetDelete('@item.Id','@Html.Raw(item.Name)')"><i class="fa fa-times" title="Delete"></i></button>
}
```

The problem is `SetDelete('@item.Id','@Html.Raw(item.Name)')`

The html renders:

```
SetDelete('43316946-4754-4059-84CE-D893D1ED9A4D','John d'Auvergne')
```

the issue is the quote, how do I format\cater for the quote '?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.javascriptstringencode(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
'@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(item.Name))'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't got strong feelings about mixed quote/single quote you could do this (flip the quotes):

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <button class="btn btn-small btn-danger btn-flat" type="button" onclick='SetDelete("@item.Id","@Html.Raw(item.Name)")'><i class="fa fa-times" title="Delete"></i></button>
}
```

If you have strong feelings about keeping the double quotes around your attributes or your dynamic strings could contain a mixture of quotes or single quotes, you might have to escape them.

```
SetDelete('@item.Id','@Html.Raw(item.Name.Replace("'", "\'"))')
```

To tidy this up further, you could move that logic to your ViewModel:

```
SetDelete('@item.Id','@item.NameJsEncoded')
```